Arabic character (Lam-Alif - لاَ) rendered differently
In the following snippet the letters are rendered correctly.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Arabic Font Rendering Test</title>
    <style>
        body {
            direction: rtl;
            text-align: right;
            margin: 20px;
            font-size: 24px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="font-family: 'KacstBook', sans-serif;">
        KacstBook: لاَ إِلَهَ إِلاَّ أَنْتَ
    </div>
</body>

</html>



From another website I checked and the text should look like bellow as expected (as shown in above snippet output).

But I am using asciidoctor-web-pdf to generate pdf from .adoc file. Here the very sentence is rendered differently:

The CSS I am using in asciidoctor-web-pdf is:
@font-face {
    font-family: 'KacstBook';
    src: local('KacstBook');
    size-adjust: 200%;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    unicode-range: U+0600-06FF, U+0750-077F, U+0870-088E, U+0890-0891, U+0898-08E1, U+08E3-08FF, U+200C-200E, U+2010-2011, U+204F, U+2E41, U+FB50-FDFF, U+FE70-FE74, U+FE76-FEFC, U+102E0-102FB, U+10E60-10E7E, U+10EFD-10EFF, U+1EE00-1EE03, U+1EE05-1EE1F, U+1EE21-1EE22, U+1EE24, U+1EE27, U+1EE29-1EE32, U+1EE34-1EE37, U+1EE39, U+1EE3B, U+1EE42, U+1EE47, U+1EE49, U+1EE4B, U+1EE4D-1EE4F, U+1EE51-1EE52, U+1EE54, U+1EE57, U+1EE59, U+1EE5B, U+1EE5D, U+1EE5F, U+1EE61-1EE62, U+1EE64, U+1EE67-1EE6A, U+1EE6C-1EE72, U+1EE74-1EE77, U+1EE79-1EE7C, U+1EE7E, U+1EE80-1EE89, U+1EE8B-1EE9B, U+1EEA1-1EEA3, U+1EEA5-1EEA9, U+1EEAB-1EEBB, U+1EEF0-1EEF1;
}

body {
    font-family: "KacstBook", "Noto Serif Bengali", "Noto Serif", serif !important;
}

What might be the issue here? Why (Lam-Alif - لاَ) is not rendered correctly?

There is a typo in your example: it should be https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Markazi+Text (you're missing the ? separator. But it seems like the designers intended (or messed up) this layout. If it's an "design bug" you can file an issue report on github

Fixed the typo. However, do you have any idea what is causing the لاَ issue for KacstBook.

@herrstrietzel I have edited the question to simplify it.

Using font-feature-settings: "liga" 1; in the body solved my issue.

It's great you got the rendering fixed! If you intend to share the PDF with others, src: local() should be changed so the font can be embedded. Using local says "don't embed this, the reader's system will have the font". That could be a problematic assumption.

@eskwayrd Thank you very much. I did not know that. I indeed need embedded fonts.
